# how to use python parse xml doc which contains character";&"

Tags: python, xml

I have an XML doc that contains characters"&;,", like this:

```
<dblp>
<article mdate="2011-12-29" key="tr/trier/MI96-15" publtype="informal publication">
<author>Manfred Laumen</author>
<title>Newton's Method for a Class of Optimal Shape Design Problems</title>
<journal>Universit&auml;t Trier, Mathematik/Informatik, Forschungsbericht</journal>
<volume>96-15</volume>
<year>1996</year>
</article>
</dblp>
```

How can I parse it?

My code is always wrong:

```
import libxml2
doc = libxml2.parseFile('dblp.xml')
```

Answer (score 3):

You need an XML DTD that defines `&auml;` and it needs to be referenced (or included) in the XML being parsed. [This looks like the one you need](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/xml/dblp.dtd). Just add an appropriate declaration, such as `<!DOCTYPE dblp SYSTEM "http://dblp.uni-trier.de/xml/dblp.dtd">` to the top of your XML file, immediately following the `<?xml ...>` declaration.

If this isn't in your file already, it's trivial to have your script add it.

You could also embed the whole DTD in your document like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?>
<!DOCTYPE dblp [
     <!-- the DTD linked above goes here -->
]>
<!-- the rest of your XML goes here -->
```

By the way, this really has little to do with Python; any XML parser you use in any language is going to choke on entities that aren't defined anywhere.

Comment: Strangely enough, including the DTD in the XML source works perfectly, but linking to the DTD does not: entities are swallowed silently by the parser. That's in particular what happens with the base dblp XML file: it already contains a link to the dtd, but in the output that the parser produces the entities are simply omitted.